# UWP Jenkins: CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file

Tags: .net, windows, jenkins, uwp

I am trying to configure a Jenkins server to build an UWP project and now I am stuck with these kind of errors:

```
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages\4.0.1\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll' could not be found [F:\jenkins\workspace\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.Core.csproj]
```

Could somebody help me? I have searched a lot on stackoverflow but none of the existing questions helped me.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution that worked for me:**
Problem was that `user.name` variale in Jenkins was pointing to the wrong location. So, I've re-installed Jenkins and had the variale pointing to `C:\Users\<user_name>\Jenkins` folder where `.nuget` folder actually exists containing all those needed packages.